# Internal build system error, read the full binlog without getting a BuildFinishedMessage, while the backend process is still running

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWRPV.png)
As you can see in this picture I'm getting an error and I can't run my project.
Could you please help me ?

NOTE -> I don't know English so I'm using translation sentences may not be correct sorry

My Unity hub version is up to date and I am using version 2022.3.4f1.
I deleted the Library/Bee folder it didn't work
I deleted the Manifest.Json file and it didn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASBLF.png)
"Editor Application" is not loaded when I want to install a different version